# Error running eject: Error: the connection was disabled

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried to `npm run eject` an expo project, I got the error when login with expo account though I can access expo web by my expo account. I created a new account expo to try access again but still return *the connection was disabled*. Pls help me solve it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

what version create-react-native-app do you have? if it is an old version, you will need to update it -- if the xdl dependency is too old, login will not work

Comment: Currently, I'm using `react-native: 0.50.3`, `react: 16.0.01`, `expo: 23.0.4`, and`sdkVersion: 23.0.0`. It 's not too old version, you can reference versions [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md)

Answer (score 0):

Please update react-native-scripts to the latest version and then run eject.

```
npm install --save-dev react-native-scripts@latest
```

It should work.